# purescript writing implementation for Eq type class

Tags: purescript

I wrote this code in purescript

```
module TypeClasses where
  import Prelude
  import Data.Array
  import Data.Number.Format(toString) 

  data Point = Point{x:: Number, y:: Number}
  instance showPoint :: Show Point where 
    show (Point {x, y}) = (toString x) <> ", " <> (toString y)    
  instance eqPoint :: Eq Point where
    eq p1 p2 = if (p1.x == p2.x && p1.y1 == p2.y2) then true else false
```

but I get error

```
Compiling TypeClasses
Error found:
in module TypeClasses
at src/TypeClasses.purs line 17, column 20 - line 17, column 22

  Could not match type

    { x :: t0
    | t1
    }

  with type

    Point


while checking that type Point
  is at least as general as type { x :: t0
                                 | t1
                                 }
while checking that expression p1
  has type { x :: t0
           | t1
           }
while checking type of property accessor p1.x
in value declaration eqPoint

where t0 is an unknown type
      t1 is an unknown type

See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/TypesDoNotUnify.md for more information,
or to contribute content related to this error.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of issues with your code:

- You have to *deconstruct* the `Point` parameters to access the "wrapped" record with your actual coordinates like this: `eq (Point p1) (Point p2)` (this will solve your type error)
- `.y1` and `.y2` do not exist, I guess you mean `.y`
- And as a hint: `if something then true else false` can be shortened to just `something`

So you will end up with this implementation of `Eq` for `Point`:

```
instance eqPoint :: Eq Point where
  eq (Point p1) (Point p2) = p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y
```